# How do I create a full Windows memory dump, preferably without causing a system crash?

Tags: windows, memory

I've been researching about creating disk images and memory dumps of a system in use for forensic purposes. I've seen that ProcDump can dump a single process' memory, but I was hoping I could find something that allowed dumping the entire memory space.

Any recommendations? It's for academic purposes, so non-paid options are preferred.

Comment: Try hibernation (hiberfil.sys), or VM with the snapshot functionality.

Comment: have you tried LiveKD?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LiveKD from sysinternals](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/SystemInformation/LiveKd.mspx) to do [create a full dump](http://www.kuskaya.info/2013/06/20/how-to-create-a-complete-memory-dump-with-livekd-exe-without-crashing-the-server/).

Copy LiveKD into the Debugging Tools folder, run it, configure the symbols and in the KD prompt type `.dump /f  D:\CompleteMemory.dmp` to generate a dump.

[image]